# solidity ^0.8.0 - receiving payment failed at require(msg.value == ___ ether)

Tags: solidity, remix

ide: remix injected web3 on ropsten network, issue:
I'm new to solidity and reverse engineering a little 3 year old project while learning the breaking change from 0.4+ to 0.8.0

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've stepped through in the debugger and it blows up at --

require(msg.value == .001 ether);

the function (in the child class) is supposed to increase the fighter's level within it's array that's ( in the parent class).
function:

```
 function levelUp(uint _fighterId) external payable {
    require(msg.value == .001 ether);
    leveladd = fighters[_fighterId].level + 1;
    fighters[_fighterId].level = leveladd;
}
```

and the same but designated 'public' instead of 'external'..

```
function levelUp(uint _fighterId) public payable {
require(msg.value == levelUpFee);
leveladd = fighters[_fighterId].level + 1;
 fighters[_fighterId].level = leveladd  ;
}
```

I've tested the function syntax without 'payment', and it's operable. When payment and msg.value is added, then metamask operates as it should when the value is being called and sent, but the transaction always fails on the contract side.

Comment: Hey, I tested it in Remix. Worked for me with no issues. Are you sure that you are sending 0.001 eth with your transaction?

Comment: I have also tested in on Rinkeby Test Network. The transaction (obviously) failed on me when I did not send any ether, but was successful when I sent 0.001 ether exactly.

Comment: Solved. The input box for 'value' has to have the correct amount entered, it's not automatically sent as along with the function request to the wallet, which I assumed. :). I didn't realise this input box is connected to the other buttons. 
Kostiantyn Kurbatskyi
 Thanks for checking!